# Error: Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, data-annotations

I try to scaffold a controller for my ClientModel and it gives me an error called:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Unable to retrieve metadata for '/////.ClientModel'. Unable to determine composite primary key for ordering for type '/////.ClientModel'. Use the ColumnAttribute (link) or the HasKey method (link) to specify an order for composite primary keys.

I have three classes with all of them an One-To-One relationship with my Client class.

This is my ClientModel:

```
[Table("Client")]
public class ClientModel : PersonModel
{
    [Key(), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    //... snip ...
    [Required]
    public long ClientIdentificationNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual PassportDetailsModel Passport { get; set; }
    public virtual MembershipClientValidationModel Membership { get; set; }
    public virtual AccountClientModel Account { get; set; }
}
```

Passport class:

```
[Table("Passport")]
public class PassportDetailsModel
{
    [Key(), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid PassportDetailsId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string IssuingCountry { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Issued { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ClientModel Client { get; set; }
}
```

Account class:

```
  [Table("AccountClient")]
public class AccountClientModel
{
    [Key(), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid AccountId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual ClientModel Client { get; set; }
}
```

Membership class:

```
[Table("MembershipClientValidation")]
public class MembershipClientValidationModel
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid MembershipClientValidationId { get; set; }
    public DateTime MembershipStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime MembershipExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsMembershipValid { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual ClientModel Client { get; set; }
}
```

I don't understand how to fix the 'unable to retrieve metadata for `<class>` error. How do I link classes with composite keys?

---

21-09-2015
After reading some comments I deleted the

```
DatabaseGenerated.DatabaseOption.Identity
```

In my primary key's in the other classes (Passport, Membership and Account). So I added some properties to my ClientModel:

```
        [ForeignKey("Passport")]
    public Guid PassportDetailsId { get; set; }
    public virtual PassportDetailsModel Passport { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Membership")]
    public Guid MembershipClientValidationId { get; set; }
    public virtual MembershipClientValidationModel Membership { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Account")]
    public Guid AccountClientId { get; set; }
    public virtual AccountClientModel Account { get; set; }
```

It still gives me the same error as it gave me above.

Comment: Please don't put 'Stuck' or 'help' in your question; we know you need help and that you're stuck, otherwise you wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker thank you for your huge advice. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Do you have a MembershipClientValidationId, AccountId, and PassportDetailsId field in your Client definition and table? The relationship definitions will use those to link the tables together.

Comment: Can you show a PersonModel class too?

Comment: You have three 1:1 association of which `ClientModel` seems to be the principle, so the other classes should have primary keys that are foreign keys to `ClientModel`. No `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`.

Comment: @Ramoth I added them and still the same result.

Comment: @GertArnold I delete the DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity in the other three classes and added the Id's of the models to my ClientModel class with [ForeignKey("")] references. It still gives me the same error.

Comment: Well, that's exactly the opposite of what I said. `PassportDetailsId` etc. should be primary key *and also* foreign key to `ClientModel`.

Comment: @GertArnold this problem is solved. I explained it with my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this problem by doing some simple changes.

I removed my three `[ForeignKey("//")]` in my ClientModel. I added the *Foreign keys* to my *Primary keys* in my other 3 models with reference to my ClientModel.

What I did next was the major fix. I added `[Required]` above the `public ClientModel Client { get; set; }` in my other three models.

Now it works and scaffolds my *ClientController* without error(s).
So to show an example of one of the other three models:

```
public class MembershipClientValidationModel
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
    public DateTime MembershipStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime MembershipExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsMembershipValid { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual ClientModel Client { get; set; }
}
```

It just works.